# Retrieving Clean JSON from Response::json

Tags: ajax, http, http-headers, laravel

I'm trying to respond to my ajax request with `Response::json()`

However the problem is no matter what the HTTP code (200 or 422) for (success/failure) the response is always in the same format and my JSON is not easily parse-able as the HTTP info is in the same field 'statusText' as my JSON so I end up with

in my **controller**

```
die(Response::json(array('message' => 'Success', 'status' => 200', 'redirect_url'=> ''), 200));
```

on javascript, **response data**

```
'status' => 200,
'statusText' =>
    "HTTP/1.0 200 OK
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Content-Type:  application/json
    Date:          Sun, 21 Jul 2013 09:51:55 GMT

    {"status":200,"statusText":"Success","redirect_url":""}"
```

I want to extract statusText string 'Success'

What's the difference if I use Laravel **Response::json** versus **json_encode**() and use php **set_status_header** which I beleive gives me the right behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. Instead of

```
die(Response::json(array('message': 'Success', 'status': 200', 'redirect_url': ''), 200););
```

use

```
die(Response::json(array('message'=> 'Success', 'status'=> 200', 'redirect_url'=> ''), 200));
```

Comment: Hi Melvin, you are right thank you I corrected it, mistyped it for the question however my problem still remains.

Answer (score 1):

Ah ok I just found the problem. Instead of doing die i should do a return then it works as expected!